# How do I produce 3 sets of 3 random numbers from 0-15 and average them into one set of three numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to recreate the algorithm in PokemonGO for IV calculation in hatched eggs.

The IVs range in value between 0-15 for attack, speed, and HP. 
Hatched eggs "roll the dice" three times per value and takes the highest one.

For example, to calculate attack IV they generate 3 random numbers and take the highest one, then again for speed, then again for HP. So for attack the numbers would be 10, 10, and 14.

It would then choose 14, speed was 11, 12, 15, so it would choose 15, and for HP it'd be 13, 13, 15, so it'd choose 15. The corresponding list would be [14, 15, 15]. How do do this? I tried and I can't get that far.

Comment: this sounds like a solid algrithm you have, what did you try? What went wrong? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: Use list.append() and max(list)

Comment: I tried doing three separate random number functions, and taking the max out of those. Then tried indexing it to a list. I have a hard time figuring out how to use move the random value generated to pass it trough a max function, then passing to a list. That's the part I can't figure out. How to pass those randomly generated numbers into different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, you create a list of random numbers by using a list comprehension with `random.randint`:

```
rolls = [random.randint(0, 15) for _ in range(3)]
#         minimum roll--^   ^--max            ^--number of rolls
```

the maximum can be determined using the built-in `max` function (in this case a generator expression instead of the list comprehension can be used):

```
max_roll = max(random.randint(0, 15) for _ in range(3))
```

It's left as an exercise to find the maximum of several of these calculations.

Comment: I tried putting the code into the prompt but it gives me no output. Am I not doing it right?

Comment: import random

rolls = [random.randint(0,15) for _ in range (3)]

max_rolls = max(random.randint(0,15) for _ in range(3))             NO OUTPUT

Comment: @RyanPostell if you want to see the result then `print` variables.